# python IDE that allows for personal color coordination

Tags: python, ide

I currently am creating regular expression patterns that take up quite a bit of line space and finding the exact points I want to change is a little difficult. I am curious if there is an IDE that allows me to change a pattern to a color of my choice.

For example my code is

```
a = re.findall(r'(?<=\w{5}\s\w{6}\s)[-\d{1}]\.\d{6}\w{1}[-+]\d{2}\s(?=
[-\d{1}]\.\d{6}\w{1}[-+]\d{2}\s[-\d{1}]\.\d{6}\w{1}[-+]\d{2})', line)

b = re.findall(r'(?<=\w{5}\s\w{6}\s[-\d{1}]\.\d{6}\w{1}[-+]\d{2}\s)[-
\d{1}]\.\d{6}\w{1}[-+]\d{2}\s(?=[-\d{1}]\.\d{6}\w{1}[-+]\d{2})', line)

c = re.findall(r'(?<=\w{5}\s\w{6}\s[-\d{1}]\.\d{6}\w{1}[-+]\d{2}\s[-
\d{1}]\.\d{6}\w{1}[-+]\d{2}\s)[-\d{1}]\.\d{6}\w{1}[-+]\d{2}', line)
```

However I would like to be able to change

```
(?=
```

and

```
(?<=
```

to a certain color so that I can easily find it within my code. I am currently using pycharm-community.

Comment: Not an answer, but you should really use verbose mode for these regexes. Regexes are code, and code needs to be readable.

Comment: Yep, you don't even need coloring if you use [the re.X flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X)

Comment: Just saying, you could break lines using `"string.." <another line> "another string"` pattern if that helps. The line breaks don't insert `\n` into the actual string unlike block strings.